# Adding signal to sensitivity list synthesizes to a buffer?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx, hdl, vivado

I'm writing a simple D-flip-flop in Verilog and looking at what it synthesizes to. Here's what I have:

```html
module d_flip_flop(
    input d,
    input clr,
    input clk,
    input ce,
    output reg q
);

always @(posedge clk) begin: d_flip_flop
    if (clr) begin
        q <= 1'b0; 
    end else if (ce) begin
        q <= d;
    end
end

endmodule
```

And it synthesizes to:
[image]

However, making this change to the code and adding CE to the sensitivity list:

```html
module d_flip_flop(
    input d,
    input clr,
    input clk,
    input ce,
    output reg q
);

always @(posedge clk or posedge ce) begin: d_flip_flop
    if (clr) begin
        q <= 1'b0; 
    end else if (ce) begin
        q <= d;
    end
end

endmodule
```

It synthesizes to:
[image]

What is going on? Why would adding CE to the sensitivity list make this synthesize to a buffer?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there something specific you want to accomplish, or are you just curious as to why that happens?

Comment: which warnings did you get from the synthesis tool for the second example?

Comment: Buffers are placed when you synthesis a file as an FPGA top file. I/O pins have IO buffers, so same is placed/shown in the schematic. This can be avoided by synthesizing in out of context `-mode out_of_context` .

Comment: @Serge there is 1 warning that says: [Synth 8-3331] design d_flip_flop has unconnected port ce

Comment: @Rakend running with -mode out_of_context just removed the buffers, but still directly connected the q pin to GND.

Comment: @JustinN it is my understanding that this should not happen. The second synthesis is clearly not what the verilog is saying to do. I wonder what's going on? Is it a synthesis issue, Vivado issue, veriolog problem, a bug??, etc.

Comment: @ItM unconnected 'ce', means dont-care. synthesis can do whatever it wants to do to it to optimize results. a buffer seems to be a logical choice (with ce == 0). Can you make sure that the `ce` is connected or is `1`?

Comment: @Serge I'm not sure I understand. You can see my verilog above. CE is an input. Synthesis thinks it's unconnected so hence the issue we see.

Comment: it means that the synthesis is confused and asks for clarification. You should provide one by fixing the warnings. For now it assumes dont-care.

Comment: It's not a legitimate warning. 'ce' is connected to a pin on the FPGA. Yes, synthesis is confused, but in that case it should error out or at least give a warning that says it can't synthesize this. I would say this is a minor bug in Vivado.

Comment: Reg : " The second synthesis is clearly not what the verilog is saying to do" What is it saying actually? According to Vivado UG901 page#257, Vivado Synthesis supports clocked event and an asynchronous set/reset events. But the code doesn't match with the template. Anyway did you try putting it in Xilinx forums? Pls share the link if you've done that.

Comment: https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Synthesis/Adding-signal-to-sensitivity-list-ruins-the-synthesis/m-p/1074388/highlight/false#M34196

Answer (score 3):

You're probably confusing the synthesis tool with that construct because it's not a normal thing to do. (There's nothing in the FPGA that directly supports that and I doubt it's even synthesizable at all.)

On the other hand, if you changed `ce` to `clr` in the sensitivity list, you should get a register with `clr` as an asynchronous reset, as that's the normal way to code that up for Xilinx.

I tried synthesizing it with Vivado and got a strange warning that didn't make sense. It's probably close enough to an async reset template that it doesn't directly error out, but ultimately not synthesizable so ends up with the output connected to `GND`.